# How to figure out a pod's namespace from within a pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

My service X is running in a pod P with Namespace N. how do I find out namespace info from withing Service X using Kubernetes go client API?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is meant by `go client API`. The pod's namespace is in `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace` so this "service X" just needs to read this file.

Alternatively, you can also use the [Downward API](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/user-guide/downward-api.md).

Comment: I could not find this file on kubernetes infra node. kubernetes has a go client to access API server instead of making curl call to REST apis directly.

Comment: That file is made available to the running application inside of the container. Have you tried accessing it from your application code?

Comment: this worked for me.  Its not fancy but easier than using the client-go package (and works for any language)

Answer (score -1):

I figured i can pass on pod, namespace and more using Environment variables while creating a new pod using go-client. The way to do it is by specifying environment variable key/val pair in PodSpec as below:

```
Env: []v1.EnvVar{
    {Name: "POD_NAME", Value: podname},
    {Name: "POD_NAMESPACE", Value: nsname},
},
```

then from within a pod, i can read this env. variables using os package.